# No carga la imagen

Tags: html, imagen

Acabo de subir un sitio web, y me encuentro con que 3 de las imágenes no se pueden cargar. Me pasó algo similar con un sitio anterior, y modificando la ruta de acceso pude solucionarlo, pero no esta vez. En el localhost se ve a la perfección, pero ahora que subí el sitio, no carga estas imágenes.

Adjunto porción de mi código a continuación:

```
<div class="carousel-item col-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <!-- <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/></svg> -->
    <img src="u277224827.childs.live/public_html/imagenes/abcposta.png" alt="">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
        <h1>Diagnóstico y tratamiento</h1>
        <h3>orientación vocacional</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probá sin usar path relativo, las imágenes según los hosts que usé yo siempre cuando las subís tienen una url la cual tenés que colocar en el src="http//:.." y siempre completa el alt="". Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya se muestra la imagen. El tema es que no me anda el carousel del Bootstrap ahora... o sea no pasan las imagenes jajaja

Comment: No, si la imagen la tenes subida al host, ésta tiene una url por ejemplo http://imagenesparacelulares.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/442538.jpg   entonces en el src="http://imagenesparacelulares.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/442538.jpg"...